# Windows installer no actualiza sobre versión antigua

Tags: c#, windows-forms, update

he creado un ejecuable con windows installer, el ejecutable funciona bien y si instalo pro separado se instala y funciona correctamente, el problema que tengo es que cuando existe una versión previa ya instalada en el equipo, no la actualiza, aunque la versión diga que esta actualizada.

Lo peculiar de esto es que aunque tenga habilitados en el setup las opciones para remover version antigua, detectar nuevas versiones.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta esta en el esamblador de windows installer, esto define que si sobrescribe o instala los nuevos bloques de código, es muy sencillo además de actualizar la versión en las propiedades del instalador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También se debe definir en el esamblador la versión actual de nuestra aplicación móvil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí encontraremos las propiedades de nuestra aplicación y una de estas es **Application**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Allí encontraremos una opción llamada **Assembly Information**, en esta vista deberemos actualizar la versión de nuestro producto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Debes actualizar no solo la versión del ejecutable si no la versión del instalador para que sobrescriba la versión previa[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no, aunque la versión aumente y en la lista de aplicaciones de windows aparezca la nueva versión, los cambio no se ven reflejados